# Trying to get a MATLAB function to take an array of inputs

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to call a numerical integration function (namely one that uses the trapazoidal method) to compute a definite integral. However, I want to pass more than one value of 'n' to the following function,

```
function I = traprule(f, a, b, n)

if ~isa(f, 'function_handle')
    error('Your first argument was not a function handle')
end

h = (b-a)./ n;
x = a:h:b; 
S = 0;
for j = 2:n
S = S + f(x(j));
end
I = (h/2)*(f(a) + 2*S + f(b)); %computes indefinite integral
end
```

I'm using; `f = @(x) 1/x`, `a = 1` and `b = 2`. I'm trying to pass `n = 10.^(1:10)` too, however, I get the following output for `I` when I do so,

```
I =

  Columns 1 through 3

   0.693771403175428   0.069377140317543   0.006937714031754

  Columns 4 through 6

   0.000693771403175   0.000069377140318   0.000006937714032

  Columns 7 through 9

   0.000000693771403   0.000000069377140   0.000000006937714

  Column 10

   0.000000000693771
```

Any ideas on how to get the function to take `n = 10.^(1:10)` so I get an output something like,

I =  0.693771403175428,  0.693153430481824, 0.693147243059937 ... and so on for increasing powers of 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script where you are calling this from, simply iterate over `n`

```
k = 3;
f = @(x)1./x;
a = 1; b = 2;
I = zeros(k,1);
for n = 1:k 
    I(n) = traprule(f, a, b, 10^n);
end

% output: I = 0.693771403175428
%             0.693153430481824
%             0.693147243059937
```

Then `I` will contain all of the outputs. Alternatively you can adapt your function to use the same logic to loop over the elements of `n` if it is passed
as a vector.

---

Note, you can improve the efficiency of your `traprule` code by removing the `for` loop:

```
% This loop operates on every element of x individually, and is inefficient
S = 0;
for j = 2:n
    S = S + f(x(j));
end
% If you ensure you use element-wise equations like f=@(x)1./x instead of f=@(x)1/x
% Then you can use this alternative:
S = sum(f(x(2:n)));
```

Comment: When I run your loop, it loops infinitely. I had the following loop myself to begin with, 

`f = @(x)1/x;
a = 1; b = 2;
I = zeros(1,10);
for j = 1:10
I(j) = traprule(f, a, b, 10^j);
end`

Comment: Do you have any idea why it won't work for larger values of k, namely 10?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, it should work for any sized `k` if your computer has enough memory to handle the increasingly large `x` vectors! I had just only tested it for `k=3` as you provided those results for comparison. Please also see my edit on improving your function :)

Comment: Wait, nevermind. It just took a while to compute 10^10. I appreciate your help, thank you!